# How do I create a Fixture in Andengine and assign it user data?

Tags: andengine, jbox2d

I´m following this tutorial: [How do I use a JBox2D ContactListener to check if my character is standing on the ground?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/61136/how-do-i-use-contactlistener-in-jbox2d) in order to get input from player's bottom part including a fixture in player's main body. 
My problem is that I´m initializing FixtureDef like this:

```
    body = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(physicsWorld, this,BodyType.DynamicBody,PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(0,0, 0));

    body.setUserData("player");
    body.setFixedRotation(true);


    // create the bottom sensor
    final FixtureDef footSensor = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(0, 0, 0);
    footSensor.isSensor = true;
    body.createFixture(footSensor);
```

Now I can't do: footSensor.setUserdata("sensor") because only Fixture class has this method. How can I initialize Fixture class to be able to include a user data? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the method you are using on this line:

```
body.createFixture(footSensor);
```

It returns the fixture:

```
public Fixture createFixture (FixtureDef def);
```

So the only thing you need to do is:

```
Fixture footSensorFixture = body.createFixture(footSensor);
footSensorFixture.setUserdata("sensor");
```

Also your naming convention is a bit confusing. You are calling a fixture definition "footSensor", but the defition is basically just the set of parameters, not the sensor itself.