# How to restrict jumping to a single jump?

Tags: physics, box2d, jbox2d

I'm making a VolleyBall game in HTML5 with PandaJs GameEngine and plugin is used physics and Box2D.

The problem is that players can jump, but they can jump over the net with multiple jumps. I have already implemented collision detection but i don't know how the restrict move space for player. I also attaching my screen shot here so look at this
: 
[image]

In the picture Player1 goes Player2 side and vise-versa.

Comment: See [The 'can I jump' question](http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/jumpability). Very good tutorial by iforce2d.

Answer (score 4):

The most common approach to this is to detect if the character is standing on a solid surface before allowing them to jump. This restricts players to a single jump since the first jump puts them in the air, then they're no longer on a solid surface, so the next time they try to jump, they can't.

For Box2D specifically you can see how to implement that here:

[How do I use a JBox2D ContactListener to check if my character is standing on the ground?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/61136/how-do-i-use-a-jbox2d-contactlistener-to-check-if-my-character-is-standing-on-th)